# CSS Grid items only grow in Chrome to max-height

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-grid

I want to achieve the following:

- have multiple images on one row with no wrap
- images shrink on smaller devices and keep aspect-ratio
- images grow on larger devices until max-height is reached
- images become centered if max-height is reached
- there should never be a gap between the images

If you view the following code snippet in Google Chrome, it is exactly what I want to achieve. However, it only works in Chrome, because they seem to handle `.grid { max-width: 100%; }` differently. Firefox for example, keeps the images shrinked. If you remove `max-width: 100%;` from `.grid` you get the same result in Chrome as with Firefox.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/markej/pen/dyGMyZO)

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, calc(100% / 5));
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="grid">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720">
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't find a way to achieve this, apart from the effect in Chrome. Is it only possible with JavaScript or did I overlook something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, it only works in Chrome, because they seem to handle `.grid { max-width: 100%; }` differently.

Sure looks that way. Use `max-width: 100vw` instead.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, calc(100% / 5));
  max-width: 100vw; /* adjustment */
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="grid">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720">
  </div>
</div>
```